# 'Workbook.open' error - Closes the file right after opening it

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get data on one hundred Excel workbooks. I created a macro to loop through those files, get the data and close them. But right after my Workbooks.open(path) opens the file, it closes it and throws a *1004 error* saying that the method 'open' failed.

I tried to open another of those one hundred files and every one of them throws the same error. I tried to open a normal file (not one of those one hundred), through the macro, it opens normally.

Copied a bunch of those to my C:\, all of them throw an error.

Recorded a macro to open the file. The file opens because I clicked File->Open File, but it throws an error if I run the macro to open it.

Obviously the problem lies in those files.

- LINK to the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B91aEt5doibuN2ktdEF4VTk2cFk/view?usp=sharing).

--> CODE:
Just a normal Workbook.open code (There is no full code, it's just it! And I get an error with the file linked)

```
Workbook.Open("C:\file.xlsx")
```

--> They Open normally by hand without any error or problem.

--> They have:
 * Querytables
 * Normal formulas
 * They are kinda small

--> Observations and what I tried:

- The paths are right (it opens the file and closes it right after, and error).
- The files I'm trying to open have connection queries, but I deleted the connections on my test files. Same error.
- Tried the CurruptLoad param, same error (I don't know if I used it right).
- Tried UpdateLinks:=0, same error.
- Tried to open it through new Excel.Application, nothing changed.
- Tried on another PC, same thing.

Anyone had something like this?

What should I try?

Comment: not sure if it would help, but what about opening as `ReadOnly`?

Comment: I assume that's a typo in the code above and it's actually `Workbooks.Open`? Does it help if you turn calculation off before opening? Can you post one of the files somewhere?

Comment: Scott - I tried as ReadOnly, nothing changed. Thanks

Comment: Rory - I tried by recording without changing the code it creates, it is Workbooks open. Thanks
I will try the calculation off. EDIT: not worked.

Comment: Update question with full code .we shall try our best to help you

Comment: Sathsh - theres no full code. The code is that, simple as that workbook.open.

the problem lies on the files and I dont know why they open and closes right after. I shared a link to the file

Comment: Edited with a link to the file. Thank you guys for the support

Comment: I have no issue opening that file in code. Can you try opening Excel in Safe Mode (hold Ctrl while starting the application) and then see if you have the same problem?

Comment: @Rory No luck with that, Tried to download the file I uploaded, same err.
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Excel? It works fine for me with 2010.

Comment: Tried in one more PC, same thing. Makes no sense to me, other files open normally.

Comment: @Rory all of us are using excel 2013.

Comment: @Rory I posted a solution to this case.
using CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData as a param for Workbooks.open let me open it with no tables, querytables, connections, etc. possibly eliminating the problem I have here. 

Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found for this case (here in my work)

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
set wb = Workbooks.Open(objFile.path, ReadOnly:=True, CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData)
wb.close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Through the CorruptLoad:=xlExtractData, it clear every table, every connection, and anything else that could be problem. I get my data and close the file without saving it.

Thanks for the support guys.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing after the open ?

If you are trying to do something else, then maybe file has not opened completely and error is based on next line not happening.

Comment: Nothing, like I said, after I got the first error, I just run a macro with Workbook.open, there's nothing after it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you can use one code that I use when I need to retrieve data from plus files (all with the same formatting )

```
Sub ImportData()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim LastRow As Long
'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

WsTo = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then Exit Sub

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xlsx"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    WsFrom = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Windows(WsTo).Activate
    Sheets(1).Select
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save and Close Workbook
    Workbooks(WsFrom).Close SaveChanges:=False
    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Importazione completata!"

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```